# calculate the dates that are between two days of the week

Tags: php

I need an algorithm that calculates dates that are between two days of the week!
for example i have

start date: 23-04-2012 and end date: 27-04-2012

now i want receive an array with this structure:

```
$arr = array(
  '23-04-2012',
  '24-04-2012',
  '25-04-2012',
  '26-04-2012', 
  '27-04-2012', 
  '28-04-2012'
);
```

thanks!

Comment: seems pretty straight forward. all you need to do is check if there is a month transition between the two dates, the other case is even more trivial than this one i.e. a simple increment loop with the month remaining the same.

Comment: I would use some combination of `strtotime` and `date`, or `DateTime`.

Comment: I would use a combination of `date`, `strtotime`, `mktime` and an incrementing variable for the day.

Comment: @deceze You *could*, though I like mktime better, use something like `strtotime("blah +{$x} days");`  But, I'm not quite sure what the daylight saving time implications of that would be (am not actually sure if mktime is 100% safe either, bu tit's definitely better).

Comment: @Corbin Yes, I have come to not trust `strtotime` too much, but that may be purely subjective. `mktime` works great, as demonstrated in my answer below... :)

Comment: @deceze That example doesn't cross a DST boundary, but I'll take your word for it because I suck at date/time math in my head (nor do I have an intimate familiarity with the inner workings of mktime) :).

Comment: @Corbin [*"mktime() is useful for doing date arithmetic and validation, as it will automatically calculate the correct value for out-of-range input."*](http://php.net/mktime) In other words, it will return the correct date for `mktime(0, 0, 0, 4, 200, 2012)` and has been explicitly created for that. :)

Comment: @deceze I'm aware that it does that, what I've had problems with in the past, however, is results being shifted enough to throw off a `<=`.  In your example, I do not believe it's possible since there will be a 24 hour gap, and even with time zones, DST couldn't skew that enough to be significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$start = '23-04-2012';
$end   = '27-04-2012';

$startTs = strtotime("$start 00:00:00");
$endTs   = strtotime("$end 00:00:00");

$days = array();
$day  = $startTs;

$i = 0;

while ($day <= $endTs) {
    $days[] = date('d-m-Y', $day);
    $i++;
    $day = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('n', $startTs), date('j', $startTs) + $i, date('Y', $startTs));
}

var_dump($days);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the DateTime::Diff function (documentation [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)).

1. Pass your two dates into the function.
2. Get the return value as the number of days.
3. Add one to it (so as to include both the start and end dates).
4. Put together a `for(int i = 0; i <= $days_difference; i++)` loop.
5. [Increment the date by one day](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) each time and add it to the array.

Comment: @Răzvan Panda: Thanks for adding the reference link.

Answer (score -1):

This could help you.

```
$startdate=explode("-","23-04-2012");
$enddate=explode("-","27-04-2012");
$i;
$arr=array();
for($i=$startdate[0];$i<=$endate[0];$i++)
{
     $dd=$i.'-'.$startdate[1].'-'.$startdate[2];
     array_push($arr,$dd);
}
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: And if this crosses a month boundary?  Date math is usually better left to date functions than string manipulation.

Comment: i just gave a sample code for the OP to start with. Now the OP can experiment with this and improve.

Comment: Up to you, of course.  Personally I avoid string-manipulation based date math at all costs, but some people use it all the time.  I believe you're leading him down the wrong path, but assuming the dates do not cross a boundary of a time period larger than or equal to a month, the code is valid.

Comment: @PsyCoder: Your method is not wrong if you modify it to work with changing months, leap years. But that would be over-complicating the problem. One could just use [datetime.add](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) and that would relieve the programmer of all that burden.